# Force Calculation at a Point Within a Vector Field, and then Reacting to that Force

Tags: matlab, vector, physics

So, this is going to be pretty hard for me to explain, or try to detail out since I only *think* I know what I'm asking, but I could be asking it with bad wording, so please bear with me and ask questions if need-be.

Currently I have a 3D vector field that's being plotted which corresponds to 40 levels of wind vectors in a 3D space (obviously). These are plotted in 3D levels and then stacked on top of each other using a dummy altitude for now (we're debating how to go about pressure altitude conversion most accurately--not to worry here). The goal is to start at a point within the vector space, modeling that point as a particle that can experience physics, and iteratively go through the vector field reacting to the forces, thus creating a trajectory of sorts through the vector field.

Currently what I'm trying to do is whip up code that would allow me to to start a point within this field and calculate the forces that the particle would feel at that point and then establish a resultant force vector that would indicate the next path of movement throughout the vector space.

Right now I'm stuck in the theoretical aspects of the code, as I'm trying to think through how the particle would feel vectors at a distance.

**Any suggestions on ways to attack this problem within MatLab or relevant equations to use?**

[image]

In order to run my code, you'll need read_grib.r4 and to compile that mex file here is a link to a zip with the code and the required files.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uodvixdff764frq/WindSim_StackOverflow_Files.zip

Comment: Any way to get a file a bit smaller than 135 MB?

Comment: Use [`interp3`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html) to calculate the force at an arbitrary point by interpolating your data points?

Comment: Luis, would you mind expanding on that? How is interpolating the data points going to help? Is it extending the vector to the point of inquiry which gives you a value / heading for that vector at the point of inquiry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to interpolate the wind vector from the adjecent ones. You seem to have a regular grid, that should be no problem. (You can use interp3 for this)

Afterwards, you can use any differential-equation solver for your problem, as you have basically a field of gradients and an initial value. Forward euler would be the simplest one but need a small step size. (N.B.: Your field *should* be a gradient field)
You may read about this in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Flow_curves

In response to comment #1:
Yes. In a regular grid, any (arbitrary chosen) point will have eight neighbors. interp3 will so a [trilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation) to determine an interpolated gradient vector.
If you use forward-euler, you will then move a small distance in that direction. There you interpolate a gradient and go a small step into this new direction and so on. What happens are two things:

1. You get a series of points that lie on a streamline and thus form the trajectory of a particle moving along the field
2. Get large errors, the further you move and the larger the step size is. Use a small step size or use a better solver (Runge-Kutta comes to my mind)

If all you want is plotting, then the [streamline](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html) function might help.

Comment: DasKrümelmonster, if you don't mind me inquiring, 

So are you saying to pick the closest vectors within this field in relation to the point, use interp3 to get the value of that vector interpolated to the point of inquiry, and calculate a resultant force after considering the vector values interpolated to the point of inquiry?

Comment: I think Yes. But the "pick the closest vectors" is already done by interp3.

Comment: When I've tried to call streamline(x,y,z, u, v, w, sx, sy, sz), I first got the issue for vectors corresponding to xyz and uvw not being 3D vectors. The second error I'm currently getting is this : 

Error using griddedInterpolant
Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension.

Error in interp1>Interp1D (line 346)
   F = griddedInterpolant(Xext,V,method);

Error in interp1 (line 241)
   Vq = Interp1D(X,V,Xq,method);

Error in stream2 (line 64)
    syi=interp1(yy(:),1:szu(1),sy(k));

Error in streamline (line 63)
      verts = stream2(x,y,u,v,sx,sy,options);